# Find elements from HTML with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to extract these values of a html code:

```
2018-04-01
1,500,552
7,211
3,710
```

I ever use find_all but my problem is In this html I don't know how can I find the elements

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests

print 'Fecha Inicio ej:2018-04-01'
start = raw_input()
print 'Fecha Fin ej:2018-04-01'
end = raw_input()
glob2 = []

urls = ['http://url.com/rtbpartners/report.php?partner=id&date_from={}&date_to={}&interval=daily'.format(start, end)]
for item in urls:
    data = requests.get(item)
    data = data.text
    print data
    soup = Soup(data, "html.parser")
    print soup.find_all('tr')
```

HTML Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>AdMedia Online Ad Network | Affiliate Advertising Solutions</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../css/admedia_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/admedia_content_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #00FF00}
-->
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    //restricting min date to 2012-09-25 to use the new report table
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: (new Date(2012, 09-1, 25)) });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: (new Date(2012, 09-1, 25)) });
});

</script>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("nav");
document.createElement("section");
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("aside");
document.createElement("figure");
document.createElement("legend");
document.createElement("footer");
</script>
<![endif] -->

</head>

<body  >


<a name="top"></a>

  <header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://admedia.com" class="admedia-logo-wrapper"><span class="admedia-logo"><span class="admedia-logo-text">a</span><span class="admedia-logo-dot">d</span></span></a>
      <!--
      <ul class="top-right-links clearfix">
        <li class="first"><a class="call-link" href="tel:18002967104"><span class="admedia-icon icon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="text">Call: (800) 296-7104</span></a></li>
        <li class="hidden-phone">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li>
          <a href="/contact-us/" class="contact-link"><span class="admedia-icon icon-bubbles" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="text">Contact Us</span></a>
          <ul class="main-sub-navigation">
            <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact-us/support_ticket/">Support Ticket</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://help.admedia.com">Help Center</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>-->


      <a id="main-navigation-dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="icon-navigation" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>

      <!--<div class=" scroll-hint scroll-hint-main"></div>-->

      <a href="#" class="scroll-hint main-scroll-hint scroll-hint-main-top-arrow"><span class="scroll-hint-icon icon-chevron-sign-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>  
      <a href="#" class="scroll-hint main-scroll-hint scroll-hint-main-bottom-arrow"><span class="scroll-hint-icon icon-chevron-sign-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>


    </div>
  </header>
  <div style="margin-top: 35px; margin-left: 20px;">
    <h2>RTB DSP Stats</h2>
    <br>
    <form name="stats" method="get" action="/rtbpartners/report.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="partner" value="empresa">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="key">
        <table border='0' cellpadding='15' cellspacing='10'>
        <tr>
            <td>Date: </td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:80px" name="date_from" id="datepicker1" value="2018-04-01"> to <input type="text" style="width:80px" name="date_to" id="datepicker2" value="2018-04-01">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Interval: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="interval">
                    <option value="daily" selected>Daily</option>
                    <option value="hourly" >Hourly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>        
    </form>
    <br><br>
            <table width="100%" class="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;" align="left">
                <b>Date</b>
              </th>

              <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;" align="left">
                <b>Requests</b>
              </th>
              <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;" align="left">
                <b>Responses</b>
              </th>
              <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;" align="left">
                <b>Impressions</b>
              </th>
              <th style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;" align="left">
                <b>Spend</b>
              </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    <tr align=center>
              <td style="padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #;" align="left">
              2018-04-01              </td>
              <td style="padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #;" align="left">
                1,500,552             </td>
              <td style="padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #;" align="left">
                7,211             </td>
              <td style="padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #;" align="left">
                3,710             </td>
              <td style="padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #;" align="left">
                1.43              </td>

            </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;"
                    align="right">
                    <b>Total:</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;"
                    align="left">
                    <b>1,500,552</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;"
                    align="left">
                    <b>7,211</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;"
                    align="left">
                    <b>3,710</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD; background-color: #A9C0C2;"
                    align="left">
                    <b>1.43</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format sample HTML code to something we can read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

for table_row in soup.find_all(name="tr"):
    if table_row.parent.name == "tbody":
        for content in table_row.find_all("td"):
            print(content.getText().strip())
```

It use BeautifoulSoup4 with Python 3, but you won't have any difficulty to adapt it for Python2.

Result:

```
2018-04-01
1,500,552
7,211
3,710
1.43
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never retrieving any elements before the for loop so the loop has nothing to look for. I would suggest placing your "find_all()" before the for loop then execute it. Then put more for loops to cycle through all the tags to find the specific  tag to look for. 
Including some if loops like

```
if tag.name == "td":
    (code here)
```

I would also suggest you look at [lxml](http://lxml.de/) use for finding specific items on a web page using xpath.